# Instagram - empty link in "pagination"

Tags: api, pagination, photo, instagram

The problem:
The second link comes with an empty parameter "pagination".
That why i can not see all the photos.

Query text (in order):
1. https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&count=100
2. https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&max_id=360226483121788237_30882660&count=100

answers:
1. {"pagination":{"next_url":"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\u0026count=100\u0026max_id=360226483121788237_30882660","next_max_id":"360226483121788237_30882660"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":
... etc.
2. {"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data": ... etc.

Somebody know any solutions?

Comment: can u specify the problem more clearly, 1. what are you trying to do, 2. the problem you got in the way, 3. what is the result you want. And would be more easier to look at the porblem if you provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally that indicates there are no more photos... How many pics do you expect? Could be, there are some private or deleted photos - the are often still counted but don't get returned.